# Inno Setup: Run program without showing a checkbox

Tags: inno-setup

I have the following lines:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"; Flags: postinstall nowait
```

I would like my app to get started without showing a checkbox (which would disallow the user to do so).

Can somebody show me how, please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are few options I can think of. The first one is to run your application from the `[Code]` section of your script, the second one is to disable that check box for your `[Run]` section entry and the third one is to hide the `RunList`.

### 1. How to manually run an application when the wizard is finished ?

I would personally prefer this way, because it's more straightforward than adding a check box and hiding it later on. You will remove your current `[Run]` section entry and call one of the following functions from the [`NextButtonClick`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptevents.htm#NextButtonClick) event method when its `CurPageID` parameter equals to `wpFinished`, which indicates the Finish button click:

- [`Exec`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_exec.htm) - executes the specified executable or batch file, using the same credentials as Setup/Uninstall.
- [`ExecAsOriginalUser`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_execasoriginaluser.htm) - executes the specified executable or batch file, using the (normally non-elevated) credentials of the user that started Setup initially
- [`ShellExec`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_shellexec.htm) - opens the specified file or performs another action specified by Verb, using the same credentials as Setup/Uninstall.
- [`ShellExecAsOriginalUser`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_shellexecasoriginaluser.htm) - opens the specified file or performs another action specified by Verb, using the (normally non-elevated) credentials of the user that started Setup initially.

Because you haven't used the [`runascurrentuser`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_runsection.htm#runascurrentuser) nor [`shellexec`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_runsection.htm#shellexec) flags, the setup internally calls a function similar to this:

```pascal
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  Result := True;
  if CurPageID = wpFinished then
    ExecAsOriginalUser(ExpandConstant('{app}\MyApp.exe'), '', '', 
      SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewNoWait, ResultCode);
end;
```

One weakness of this solution is that the program would be executed even if the restart is requested by the setup. To workaround a missing possibility to determine this request we can check if the `YesRadio` is visible (it is the *Yes, restart the computer now* radio button) and selected, which means that the user was asked to restart the computer and confirmed it. Here is the version considering the restart request:

```pascal
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  Result := True;
  // if the "Finish" button was clicked and "Yes, restart the computer now"
  // radio button was either not visible or not selected that time, then...
  if (CurPageID = wpFinished) and ((not WizardForm.YesRadio.Visible) or 
    (not WizardForm.YesRadio.Checked))
  then
    ExecAsOriginalUser(ExpandConstant('{app}\MyApp.exe'), '', '', 
      SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewNoWait, ResultCode);
end;
```

### 2. How to disable the post install check box on the final page ?

Another option is to disable the check box. The user will see that the application is going to be executed, but won't be able to do anything against it (except killing the setup from Task Manager, of course). This time you will keep your `[Run]` section entry as it, but modify the `RunList` from the `[Code]` section:

```pascal
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName=My Program

[Files]
Source: "MyApp.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"; Flags: postinstall nowait

[Code]
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  // you must do this as late as possible, because the RunList is being modified
  // after installation; so this will check if there's at least one item in the
  // RunList and then set to the first item (indexing starts at 0) Enabled state
  // to False
  if (CurPageID = wpFinished) and (WizardForm.RunList.Items.Count > 0) then
    WizardForm.RunList.ItemEnabled[0] := False;
end;
```

### 3. How to completely hide the RunList ?

This will, contrary to the second option, do what you asked for. It will keep the check box hidden, or to be more precise, it will hide the whole `RunList`, so if you were having more than one entry in the `[Run]` section with the [`postinstall`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_runsection.htm#postinstall) flag specified, it won't be seen as well:

```pascal
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName=My Program

[Files]
Source: "MyApp.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"; Flags: postinstall nowait

[Code]
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpFinished then
    WizardForm.RunList.Visible := False;
end;
```

Comment: I went with [Code]
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpFinished then
    WizardForm.RunList.Visible := False;
end;

Comment: That option is safe enough if you don't plan to add another check box which you'll want to keep visible one day.

Comment: 4th option is completely disabling the Finish page with `DisableFinishedPage=yes` in the [setup] section. But i don't know if that is desirable. You don't get the last page to click "Finish". Instead your program just starts.

Comment: well just want to add this here, I was trying to use TLama way for disabling all checkbox in finish pages, at first I tried to disable them manually by giving index, but seems like in inno setup all item didn't create at same time, so it lead me to out of range error, what I did was creating a loop like this `for i := 0 to WizardForm.RunList.Items.Count - 1 do...` it did the job...

Answer (score 1):

Works on version 5.5.7

Add the following code if you want to open a website automatically

```
[Code]
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
var
  ErrorCode : Integer ;
begin
  if CurPageID = wpFinished then
    ShellExecAsOriginalUser('', ExpandConstant('http:\\www.google.pt'), '', '',SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewNoWait, ErrorCode);
end;
```